# How to implement iGlobalTime for a GLSL fragment shader in C++?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, glsl, shader

Currently I have a tiny C++ application which display a triangle by these two shaders:

Vertex shader:

```
static const char *vertex_shader_glsl = \
"#version 430\n"

"layout (location=0)in vec2 inVer;"
"out vec2 p;"
"out gl_PerVertex"
"{"
"vec4 gl_Position;"
"};"

"void main()"
"{"
"gl_Position=vec4(inVer,0.0,1.0);"
"p=inVer;"
"}";
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 430


out vec4 fragColor;
in vec2 fragCoord;
vec2 iResolution;
//uniform float iGlobalTime;
float a = -2;

void main()
{
    a = sin(-2);
    //Colors
    vec3 fgColor = vec3(0.741, 0.635, 0.471);
    vec3 bgColor = vec3(0.192, 0.329, 0.439);

    //Triangle barycentric coordinates defined on screen space


    vec2 t0 = vec2(0.25, 0);
    vec2 t1 = vec2(0.75, 0.25);
    vec2 t2 = vec2(0.50, 0.85);
    vec2 tCentroid  = (t0 + t1 + t2)/3.0;    
    //Compute UV coordinates
    vec2 uv = fragCoord.xy;

    vec2 v0 = t2 - t0;
    vec2 v1 = t1 - t0;
    vec2 v2 = uv - t0;

    //Compute barycentric coordinates 
    float dot00 = dot(v0, v0);
    float dot01 = dot(v0, v1);
    float dot02 = dot(v0, v2);
    float dot11 = dot(v1, v1);
    float dot12 = dot(v1, v2);

    float invDenom = 1.0/(dot00 * dot11 - dot01 * dot01);
    float baryX = (dot11 * dot02 - dot01 * dot12) * invDenom;
    float baryY = (dot00 * dot12 - dot01 * dot02) * invDenom;

    if((baryX >= 0.0) && (baryY >= 0.0) && (baryX + baryY <= 1.0)) {
        fragColor = vec4(fgColor, 1.0);
    } else {
        fragColor = vec4(bgColor, 1.0);
    }
}
```

This two shaders display a simple triangle:

[image]

However I would like to rotate this triangle so I would need some timer implmemntation (iGlobalTime).

I mean, I know that I would need something like this:
https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Xtt3WX

However I cannot copy-paste the code from the link above, since I'm unable to use iGlobalTime in my C++ project. How to update the shaders above to be able to rotate the triangle based on the system time? How to implement iGlobalTime in a very basic C++ application?

===========================

## EDITED

I've updated:

ext.h:

```
...
    #ifdef DEBUG
    #define NUMFUNCTIONS 14 // <<== HERE
    #else
    #define NUMFUNCTIONS 12 // <<== HERE
    #endif

    extern void *myglfunc[NUMFUNCTIONS];

    #define glCreateShaderProgramv         ((PFNGLCREATESHADERPROGRAMVPROC)myglfunc[0])
    #define glGenProgramPipelines          ((PFNGLGENPROGRAMPIPELINESPROC)myglfunc[1])
    #define glBindProgramPipeline          ((PFNGLBINDPROGRAMPIPELINEPROC)myglfunc[2])
    #define glUseProgramStages             ((PFNGLUSEPROGRAMSTAGESPROC)myglfunc[3])
    #define glProgramUniform4fv            ((PFNGLPROGRAMUNIFORM4FVPROC)myglfunc[4])
    #define glGenFramebuffers              ((PFNGLGENFRAMEBUFFERSPROC)myglfunc[5])
    #define glBindFramebuffer              ((PFNGLBINDFRAMEBUFFERPROC)myglfunc[6])
    #define glTexStorage2D                 ((PFNGLTEXSTORAGE2DPROC)myglfunc[7])
    #define glDrawBuffers                  ((PFNGLDRAWBUFFERSPROC)myglfunc[8])
    #define glFramebufferTexture           ((PFNGLFRAMEBUFFERTEXTUREPROC)myglfunc[9])
    #define glProgramUniform1f             ((PFNGLPROGRAMUNIFORM1FPROC)myglfunc[10]) // <<== ADDED NEW LINE HERE
    #define glGetUniformLocation           ((PFNGLGETUNIFORMLOCATIONPROC)myglfunc[11]) // <<== ADDED NEW LINE HERE

    #ifdef DEBUG
    #define glGetProgramiv          ((PFNGLGETPROGRAMIVPROC)myglfunc[12])
    #define glGetProgramInfoLog     ((PFNGLGETPROGRAMINFOLOGPROC)myglfunc[13])
    #endif
...
```

updated ext.cpp:

```
...
static char *strs[] = {
    "glCreateShaderProgramv",
    "glGenProgramPipelines",
    "glBindProgramPipeline",
    "glUseProgramStages",
    "glProgramUniform4fv",
    "glProgramUniform1fv",
    "glGenFramebuffers",
    "glBindFramebuffer",
    "glTexStorage2D",
    "glDrawBuffers",
    "glFramebufferTexture",
    "glProgramUniform1f",        // <<== ADDED NEW LINE HERE
    "glGetUniformLocation",      // <<== ADDED NEW LINE HERE

    #ifdef DEBUG
    "glGetProgramiv",
    "glGetProgramInfoLog",
    #endif
    };
...
```

updated intro.cpp:

```
...
    void intro_do(long time)
    {
    ...
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
        glBindProgramPipeline(renderingPipeline);
        // Set fparams to give input to shaders

        // Render
        glProgramUniform4fv(fragmentShader, 0, 4, fparams);
        glProgramUniform1f(fragmentShader, glGetUniformLocation(fragmentShader, "iGlobalTime"), time*1000); // <<== ADDED NEW LINE HERE
        glRects(-1, -1, 1, 1); // Deprecated. Still seems to work though.

    ...
    }
```

Application now runns, but crashes immediatelly saying: "Unhandled exception at 0x7542CB49 in 4kIntro.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000."

Comment: Same as any other uniform?

Comment: I've tried it already: writing "uniform float iGlobalTime;" resulted iGlobalTime=0 constantly. It seems like nothing incremented it.

Comment: Yes, OpenGL doesn't know that iGlobalTime is supposed to be the time, you have to set it yourself (like any other uniform).

Comment: This makes sense, but how to set it up, please? This is the question here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this (you need a c++11 compliant compiler)

```
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    // init stuff

    // game loop
    using Clock = std::chronohigh_resolution_clock;
    using TimePoint = std::chrono::time_point<Clock>;

    TimePoint t0, t1;
    float global_time = 0;
    t0 = Clock::now();
    while (run_game)
    {
        // dt is the time since last frame
        // global_time is the total time since the start of the game loop
        t1 = Clock::now();
        float dt = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<float, std::chrono::seconds::period>>(t1 - t0);
        global_time += dt;

        // Send your uniform and kickoff rendering
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps (there might be some typos in the code I did not check it)

EDIT:
It looks like you misunderstood some stuff so I will try to explain a bit more how stuff happens.

#### Shaders

According to [the OpenGL wiki](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Shader), a shader is "a user-defined program designed to run on some stage of a graphics processor which purpose is to execute one of the programmable stages of the rendering pipeline."

So what this means is that, when you ask the GPU to draw stuff (*via* a **draw call** , i.e. `glDrawArrays` or `glDrawElements`) it will call, for each vertex, the *vertex shader*, then, for each fragment, the *fragment shader*. (this is very simplified, for a more complete explanation about the whole pipeline you can refer to [this OpenGL wiki](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Rendering_Pipeline_Overview)).

#### Communication between the CPU and the GPU

Before calling `glDrawArrays` or `glDrawElements` you had first to send the GPU the vertices you wanted it to draw.

You did something in your c++ code like (this might not be the exact same code, don't worry about it)

```
GLfloat data[] = { ... } // The data you want to send
GLuint vao, vbo;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof data, data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (GLvoid*)0);
```

Here, you send some vertex array to the GPU and, on each element of it, your *vertex shader* will be executed, everytime you issue a *drawcall*.
In it you output a `gl_Position`, which will then be rasterized by the GPU and input to the *fragment* (or pixel) *shader*. Here, for each fragment / pixel your shader will be executed.

"This is fine, but how do I send global data to the GPU ?"
This is where `uniform`s come into play. You can send per-shader data to the GPU using them. This is done in your c++ code something like

```
GLuint location = glGetUniformLocation(program_id, "uniform_name");
glUniform_(location, uniform_data);
```

Since the OpenGL API is written in C, all the `glUniform` calls are postfixed by the type of data you want to send (see [the docs](http://docs.gl/gl4/glUniform) for all the calls). Then, after sending the data, you are able to use it in the shader.

Be careful, declaring a uniform in a shader is not enough, you have to send data to the GPU too. This is the same as any variable in C++, as long as you do not affect it anything it won't have a reliable value.

In your case, since you want to send a float uniform, called `iGlobalTime`, you will have something like

```
GLuint time_loc = glUniformLocation(program_id, "iGlobalTime");
glUniform1f(time_loc, global_time)
```

The updated c++ code taking most of this into account is

```
#include <chrono>
int main()
{
    // init stuff
    // Compile your shader_program and store its id in program_id
    // Set the vertex data on the GPU

    // game loop
    using Clock = std::chronohigh_resolution_clock;
    using TimePoint = std::chrono::time_point<Clock>;

    TimePoint t0, t1;
    float global_time = 0;
    t0 = Clock::now();

    while (!quit)
    {
        // dt is the time since last frame
        // global_time is the total time since the start of the game loop
        t1 = Clock::now();
        float dt = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<float, std::chrono::seconds::period>>(t1 - t0);
        global_time += dt;

        // Activate program
        glUseProgram(program_id);
        // Send global_time uniform
        glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(program_id, "iGlobalTime"), global_time);

        // Issue draw call
        glBindVertexArray(vao);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 4);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you mean I can implement this code right into the fragment shader?

Comment: No it should be in your c++ code, I will make this a bit more cleaner once I have access to a computer

Comment: Thanks in advance.

Comment: I updated the answer, tell me if there is anything still unclear.

Comment: Actually, I did not point out the fact that your shaders remain the same, all of the code I showed is on the c++ side

Comment: Thanks mate. I'll be back to my computer 2 days from now. Then I'll try out your source code and I will come back to you with the results. Until then I'm reading your answer and learning... Cheers.

Comment: this is the template which I'm trying to update with iGlobalTime: https://github.com/in4k/4k-Intro-Template
  I don't know where to implement "glUniform1f()".

Comment: In intro_do I guess

Comment: if my understanding is correct then in this particular template we do not need chrono since intro_do() already has a 'time' parameter. We only need to pass this parameter to glUniform1f, right?

Comment: You get a long, so I guess this is milli- micro- or nano-seconds, so you might need a bit of conversion if you want seconds, but yeah you can use this value

Comment: Either we use your solution:   [glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(program_id, "iGlobalTime"), time * 1000);]    OR something like this:    [shader.setUniform1f("iGlobalTime", time * 1000)]    we must have "program_id" or "shader". My question is regarding to this i4k_Framework template: how can I get "program_id" or "shader" for example? How could I make iGlobalTime work for this framework? A code sample in your original answer would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You have everything in intro.cpp to do what you want. You just have to replace `glUniform` by `glProgramUniform` and `program_id` by `fragmentShader`...

Comment: Yes, right. Spent several hours to implement your thoughts. I think, I'm very close now... Please see my "Edited" part of my original question. (Everything seems perfect now: application now runns, but crashes.)

Comment: I guess you will have to debug your program and post a new question if you can't find what goes wrong here, but this is not the place to discuss about it

Comment: I'll do so. Thank you for your suggestions, mate.